# collapsed div when adding float

Tags: css

I have a div with an unordered list that has a border around it. When I set the text inside it to float left it collapses the div and the border squashes upward.

Not sure why this is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/jSvdW/

Updated: I just want to first say thanks to everyone for their response and it helped me understand this question in a better light. I found a link that I think might benefit someone who runs into this issue, which explains both the overflow:hidden and clear float technique, in a very simplified manner. It also covers floats in detail.
http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.support .hnav li {
   display: inline-block;  //from inline 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/jSvdW/1/

Comment: So by using inline-block no need for float in the a tags.

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of the `float` in `.support .hnav li a`.

Answer (score 1):

change this css:

```
.support .hnav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url("sprites/sprite-icons.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

is that what you were wanting?

Answer (score 0):

An element does not automatically expand to contain floated children.

Use a [clear fix method](http://google.com/search?q=clear%20fix).

I would use `overflow: hidden` on the parent element in this example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UQFu2/).

Comment: Cool works so why does overflow:hidden on the parent make it work. Can you explain a little thanks

Comment: @Chapsterj: It just does :) Consult the first link in the answer.

Comment: So its magic another great css trick that can't be explained :) I didn't see anything about the overflow with the clear fix methods. But I'll google it and see if I can find why overflow on the parent fixes it. Thanks it works which is great